# changing fasta headers to contain count info

Tags: unix, header, fasta

I have a file with several rows like this:

> fg-000001    ATGGATGACCGATGCTAGC 34    23    33    45    34    23    34    35    34    35    56    47

I would like to convert it to just a fasta file with the sum of the count info along with the name basically a fasta file

> fg-000001_x433
>   ATGGATGACCGATGCTAGC

Is that possible?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` script should do what you are asking:

```
awk '{sum=0; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {sum += $i}; print $1"_x"sum, $2}' file
```